# how to connect two layouts in eclips

Tags: android-layout

I'm beginner in Java Android developing. i have two XML file in res/layout/. named **activity_fast_tip.xml** and **activity_setting.xml** i can't  connect these two component together. in `activity_setting.xml`

```
@Override

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_fast_tip);

  tipPctTextView=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tipPctTextView);
  tipAmountTextView=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tipAmtTextView);
  totalAmountTextView=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.totalAmtTextView);
  calcTipAmountButton=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.calcTipButton);
  billAmountTextView=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.billAmtEditText);

  calcTipAmountButton.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
  {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  calculateTip();
  }
  });
  }
```

and in `activity_fast_tip`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FastTipActivity" >

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/billAmtEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/billAmount"
        android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/calcTipButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/billAmtEditText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/calculateTip" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/billAmtEditText"
        android:layout_below="@id/calcTipButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/tipPercentage"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/tipAmount" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/totalAmount"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FF0000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/billAmtEditText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:text="@string/button" />
```

Comment: not clear what r u trying to do

Comment: i have two layouts. and i want to connect these together.

Answer (score 0):

use layout inflater
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

or Include

```
    <include
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     layout="@layout/activity_setting"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **u can use [`include` tag](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) a layout like this into `another layout`**

`titlebar.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

`some other layout` where we include that `titlebar.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

2. **u can use [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)**
`code snippet`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View someView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ur_layout,null); //2nd parameter is for viewgroup
which_layout_u_want_to_add.addView(someView);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html